# Problemas com ws

Tags: java, restful

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Pessoal estou quando executa a pagina pra gerar o json ele so tras null , ja verifiquei ele esta pegando os dados do banco o estranho e q esta dando essa mensagem :

> Informações:   Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the
>   packages:   Resource Informações:   Root resource classes found:
>   class Resource.estoqueResource Informações:   No provider classes
>   found. Informações:   Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey:
>   1.11 12/09/2011 10:27 AM'

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Resource;

import Controller.estoqueControler;
import Model.ESTOQUE;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/**
 *
 * @author Felipee[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
 */
@Path("/estoque")
public class estoqueResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/Estoque")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public ArrayList<ESTOQUE> ESTOQUE() {
        return new estoqueControler().ESTOQUE();
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o código.

Comment: postei , so nao conseguir deixar da forma correta ali

Comment: algueemmmmm ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Jersey não suporta serialização automática de qualquer tipo, no caso `ArrayList`.

Um `Provider` é um tipo especial de classe que verifica o tipo de retorno do método e o formato que ele está produzindo e, caso seja compatível, ele atua serializando o objeto naquele formato.

Você pode escrever o seu próprio `Provider`, mas a solução mais fácil é fornecer um objeto no retorno que seja compatível com um provider já existente. Basta criar uma classe anotada com `@XmlRootElement` e colocar um atributo com a lista dentro do objeto.

Outra opção é serializar a lista dentro do método usando diretamente uma biblioteca de JSON e retornar uma `String`, pois nesse caso o Jersey não vai precisar de um `Provider`. A vantagem desta abordagem é a flexibilidade, mas também deixa o código mais "sujo".